# TravisCI with Intel compiler

Tags: travis-ci, intel-composer

Does anyone have a solution for using intel tools (ifort and icc) on TravisCI? The problem is in getting the compilers on to the image and obtaining the proper license.

Here's a shell script which installs Intel 2016 and I've been passing a temporary Intel license to the Travis container as a "secret" set through the Travis dashboard. However, this script at times fails to install the intel compilers due to timeout. When it does work, it eats up about 5 minutes of my precious free time on travis so my test suite may not finish (a long test suite is its own issue, working on it).

Is it possible to create a custom Travis image which includes the tools I need for my tests? Any other ideas for using a licensed compiler and specifically the intel compiler on TravisCI?

Comment: I share your pipe dream

Comment: I've since given up working with TravisCI and have moved to GitHub Actions where working with Docker is very easy. One could distribute a Docker image with the Intel compiler preinstalled. At your own risk, though, as this probably violates the EULA.